# Are we allowed to re-post deleted questions when the original poster deleted it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A good question was asked by a newcomer, and I spent 44 minutes typing up an answer.  While I was typing, the question had been deleted by its author.  But I had a thorough answer.  Would it be a copyright infringement to re-ask the same question, and to post my answer?

Comment: Questions and answers are CC licensed so as long as you follow the CC license you can do whatever you want. However, if the question was deleted then chances are that it is not useful or not a good fit for SO, in which case you should of course not repost it.

Comment: No, it was a good question, and had a couple of upvotes beside mine.  Maybe the fact that the author was a newcomer had something to do with why he deleted it.  On the other hand, maybe this question is not a good question, seeing it's getting downvoted...

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518273/grid-nice-problem/3518312#3518312

Comment: You're on the wrong page then. Why not ask [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com) when it's about a question from their site?

Comment: While your general question is fine here, if asking about a specific post, you should probably ask in that site's meta.

Comment: @BDL The question here does not mention a specific post. It can be asked and answered here. If they want to ask something about that specific question... then yes, they should go to their meta.

Comment: @Alex often questions from newcomers get deleted as result of what I think teacher sending mail to the class like "I've noticed that authors of couple new questions on SO/Math completely misread the assignment. Please review your homework carefully" :) which in no way makes the question *as asked* invalid (the question may have totally be not one OP wanted to ask or it violates some school guidance, but neither is reason why it can't be present on the site)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you believe the Q&A would be useful for future visitors, just re-ask the question.

Instead of copying it verbatim, just re-write it using your own words, trying to make it as useful as possible for a general audience.

That way you have a valid use for your already written answer, and do not have to worry yourself about "copying" a question, even if deleted.

Comment: I would also add "Search for duplicates before posting"

Comment: Well, you should think of that before even _answering_, but yeah.